# How to undo ctrl + windows + t?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I keep doing this dumb thing where I'm just trying to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab in Chrome but I ham-handedly press the windows key button as well and accidentally press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and it closes the window with all my tabs and I can't open it again. Specifically speaking, a chrome group for a separate google user I use for work.
So my question is, how do I undo this without Logging out and logging back in? I can't find out the windows command I'm actually doing from some Google searches.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  At the risk of posing an obvious question, if this keyboard shortcut has become overtly problematic, have you considered simply using the mouse/cursor to open a new tab?

Comment: This is true, I could totally do that although my preference is to use the keyboard more and mouse less generally speaking. I suppose some of my question is curiosity at this point for what the purpose of that shortcut is at this point as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can undo it by pressing ctrl + win + T again. As for what it does, it sounds like you probably have Windows PowerToys installed. It's the shortcut to keep a window always on top. Good for playing videos or for keeping an eye on email or chat during the workday.